# Is there an alternative of UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton for iOS7 which has backward compatibility?

Tags: iphone, ios6, ios7, compatibility

I was using

```
 cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
```

in my application for  iOS-6 and lower versions.But, the code crashed for iOS-7.
So I replaced the code with

```
 cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton;
```

But this does not have a backward compatibility with iOS-6.

Is there any other generic solution rather then keeping a check for versions in if-else loops?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can create your own button and add it to cell as subview  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388812/add-button-to-uitableviewcells-accessory-view

Comment: That would require huge changes through out the application, isn't there a generic method available..??

Answer (score 0):

There is no method other than accessoryType. You have to add a custom view into the cell for this. You can easily do that by adding below lines of code in the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate of UITableView:

```
UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] init];
subView.Frame = CGRectMake(10,3,20,20);
subView.tag = 1;
[cell.contentView addSubview:subView];
[subView release];
```